# Qsort with pointer to field segmentation fault

Tags: c

I want to sort my pointer of type `(*double)[3]` according to `0` column `pnt[i][0]`. So for example from

```
4 3 4
2 1 2
9 4 5
```

I want

```
2 1 2
4 3 4
9 4 5
```

I have a call to the quicksort function

```
qsort (pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(double), forQs);
```

with forQs as follows

```
int forQs (const void *x, const void *y)
{
    const double **k = (const double **)x; 
    const double **l = (const double **)y;
    return (*k)[0] - (*l)[0];
}
```

I end up with segmentation fault and valgrind says it's because of forQs. I was exploring before a lot how to create it as I don't know `qsort` much, but I can't see there any mistake. Can anyone help?

edit: I also used:

```
pnt = (double (*)[3]) malloc(100 * sizeof(*pnt));
```

Comment: Please show the declarations for `pnt`, `numOfRows` and `forQs`. And by showing, I mean please edit the question to include those.

Comment: pnt = (double (*)[2]) malloc(100 * sizeof(*pnt)), num of rows is growing with each read row at allocation (so is already set at the time it goes to qsort), forQs is in the question

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo here. i have there pnt = (double (*)[3]) malloc(100 * sizeof(*pnt)), so that's not the problem

Comment: Don't post fixes in comments. Edit your post instead. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make two samples,  because you are not good enough unknown.
Please refer to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int forQs (const void *x, const void *y)
{
    const double **k = (const double **)x; 
    const double **l = (const double **)y;
    return (*k)[0] - (*l)[0];
}

int main(){
    double **pnt = malloc(100*sizeof(double(*)[3]));
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        pnt[i] = malloc(sizeof(double[3]));

    memcpy(pnt[0], (double [3]){4.0, 3.0, 4.0}, sizeof(double[3]));
    memcpy(pnt[1], (double [3]){2.0, 1.0, 2.0}, sizeof(double[3]));
    memcpy(pnt[2], (double [3]){9.0, 4.0, 5.0}, sizeof(double[3]));

    {//print before sort
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;++i){
            for(j=0;j<3;++j)
                printf("%g ", pnt[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    int numOfRows = 3;
//  qsort(pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(double*), forQs);
    qsort(pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(*pnt), forQs);
    {//print after sort
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;++i){
            for(j=0;j<3;++j)
                printf("%g ", pnt[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int forQs (const void *x, const void *y)
{
    const double (*k)[3] = *(const double (**)[3])x; 
    const double (*l)[3] = *(const double (**)[3])y;
    return (*k)[0] - (*l)[0];
}

int main(){
    double (**pnt)[3] = malloc(100*sizeof(*pnt));
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<3;++i)
        pnt[i] = malloc(sizeof(double[3]));

    memcpy(pnt[0], (double [3]){4.0, 3.0, 4.0}, sizeof(double[3]));
    memcpy(pnt[1], (double [3]){2.0, 1.0, 2.0}, sizeof(double[3]));
    memcpy(pnt[2], (double [3]){9.0, 4.0, 5.0}, sizeof(double[3]));

    {//print before sort
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;++i){
            for(j=0;j<3;++j)
                printf("%g ", (*(pnt[i]))[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");

    }
    int numOfRows = 3;
    //qsort(pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(double(*)[3]), forQs);
    qsort(pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(*pnt), forQs);

    {//print after sort
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<3;++i){
            for(j=0;j<3;++j)
                printf("%g ", (*(pnt[i]))[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Protip: `typedef` the thing you want work with and stick to it throughout.

Want vectors of 3 doubles?

```
typedef double vec3[3];
```

Now when you rewrite your code in terms of `vec3`, the problems become readily apparent.

```
qsort (pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(double), forQs); /* was */
qsort (pnt, numOfRows, sizeof(vec3), forQs); /* now */

const double **k = (const double **)x; /* was */
const vec3* k = (const vec3*)x; /* now */
```

This way you automatically get correct code without having to think about how and when your arrays become pointers (hint: they don't).